# Interesting real-valued function problem

Tags: functions, real-numbers

Find all real-valued functions $f(m),m\in \mathbb R$ such that for $\forall x,\forall y \in \mathbb R$ $$f((x-y)^2)= (f(x))^2 - 2xf(y) + y^2.$$
I tried several ideas, one of them is taking special $x,y$ , for example one of them $0$ or both.But i didn't get anything useful from that.Maybe there is a certain approach to such problems that i don't know.If the solution is not obvious, please describe your thought process, how you came up with that, in order for me to learn as much as possible from you.
Thanks!

Comment: The domain of $f$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $x=y=0$, we have $f(0)=f(0)^2$, hence $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$.
With $x=y$, we get $$\tag1f(0)=f(x)^2-2xf(x)+x^2=(f(x)-x)^2.$$ Hence if $f(0)=0$, we immedieatly get $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, a first solution.

Assume therefore that $f(0)=1$, i.e. we get $f(x)=x\pm1$ from $(1)$, where the sign may depend on $x$.
Let $s(x)=f(x)-x\in\{-1,1\}$. Then the functional equation gives us
$$(x-y)^2+s((x-y)^2) = (x+s(x))^2-2x(y+s(y))+y^2 $$
i.e.
$$s((x-y)^2) = 2x(s(x)-s(y))+1 $$
for all $x,y$. Especially, $s((2-y)^2)=4(s(2)-s(y))+1$ for all $y$, which is only possible if $s$ is constant. This gives us $f(x)=x+1$ for all $x$, our second solution (verify!).

Comment: Nailed, as usual